# Notepad++ Как удалить всё между двумя словами?

Tags: notepad++

Нужно найти и удалить/заменить всё содержимое между `</description>`  и `</offer>`.

```
</description>
    <sales_notes>предоплата</sales_notes>
    <param name="Тип УЗО">Выключатель</param>
    <param name="Номинальный ток" unit="А">16.0</param>
    <param name="Степень защиты IP">20</param>
    <param name="Тип монтажа">На DIN рейку</param>
  </offer>
```

Answer (score 5):

Найти: **`</description>([\s\S]*?)</offer>`**
Заменить на: **`</description></offer>`**

- `[\s\S]` - любой символ, включая переносы строк, табуляцию и тд.;
- `*?` - "не жадный" режим - минимальное подходящее совпадение;

Comment: **UModeL** правильно написал, только есть маленькая ошибка, надо снять галку с "и новые строки".

Answer (score 0):

Введите в строке поиска запрос по примеру и поставьте галки "регулярное выражение" и "новые строки", как на скриншоте.

```
</description>.*</offer>
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: В фале таких повторений очень много. Надо чтобы поиск прошелся по каждому. А то он снес все, оставив только одно совпадение.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что поиск берет первый </description> и последний </offer> в конце файла и сносит всё.

Comment: @Content02, вопросик добавь, как в соседнем ответе.