# Между кодом удалить текст и заменить на пусто

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Требуется между кодом удалить текст и заменить на пусто. Это код между которым нужно удалить текст:

Применяю рег. выражения:

```
^<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]></content:encoded>$

^<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]></content:encoded>$
```

Найти: `(^<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[)(.*)(\]\]></content:encoded>$)`
Заменить на: $1$3

Все рег. выражения, ни чего не находит и соответственно не меняют.

Возможно не работает по причине того, что в том тексте, что между кодом, так-же присутствуют символы?
Выглядит это так:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=10011"> </a>
<!--more--><!--noteaser-->
[sc_embed_player_template1 fileurl="X_X" autoplay="true" loops="true"]
<div class="vsp_1"></div>
<div class="vsp_2"></div>
<div class="vsp_3"></div>
[bc_collapse title="Все лучшее для вас" open="y/n"] [/bc_collapse] ]]></content:encoded>
```

Подскажите что не так ?

Comment: Для замены любых символов, лучше использовать не `.` (точка), а комбинацию `[\s\S]`, которая позволяет захватывать большинство непечатных символов (`\n \r \t` и тп.) и не требует выставления дополнительных галочек - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932462/265406

Comment: @UModeL - Не работает

Comment: смотрите ответ. Ну и пользуйтесь онлайн-сервисами (например, https://regexr.com/) - они сильно помогают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Найти: **`(<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[)([\s\S]*?)(\]\]><\/content:encoded>)`**

   - `[\s\S]` *- любой символ, включая переносы строк, табуляцию и тд.;*
   - `*?` *- "не жадный" режим - минимальное подходящее совпадение;*
   - `\/` *- не забываем экранировать обратные слэши.*
2. Заменить на: **`$1$3`**
3. Режим поиска: Регуляр. выражен.
4. <kbd>Заменить все</kbd>

Comment: @UModeБлагодарю. Это работает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить галочку "и новые строки" в окне поиска и замены.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, зачем вы удалили вчерашний такой же вопрос, где я уже дал рабочий проверенный ответ:

Жадный: `^<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]></content:encoded>$`

Нежадный: `^<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]></content:encoded>$`

Выставьте галочки следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, ваш рабочий проверенный ответ не работает.

Comment: Как именно не работает? У меня все работает.

Comment: Как "так"? Не находит? Не заменяет? Заменяет, но не то/не на то?

Comment: 1. Не находит
2. Соответственно НЕ заменяет.

Comment: Значит в вопросе не те данные, с которыми вы работаете или вы неправильно применяете регулярное выражение (скорее всего). Я проверял его на вашем примере. Все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Ну как неправильно применяю. Если копирую рег. выражение как здесь подсказали и все делаю точно так!